# Can the high_voltage gem handle .haml.html files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, haml

The documentation doesn't mention haml, and I couldn't find the answer by googling. Has anyone gotten this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm dumb! Because the gem 'haml-rails' was showing up in the output of `rvm gem list` I assumed it was installed... it wasn't!